# Twitter bootstrap two column rendering in jade?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

I know how to make the blocks look in bootrstrap but i dont know how to make it in jade.
The structure should look like this

```
// Input
for post in posts

// Output should be this
div.row
  /// Looped from each
  div.span6

    ..More content POST 1
  div.span6  
    ..More content POST 2
div.row
  /// Looped from each
  div.span6
    ..More content POST 3
  div.span6  
    ..More content POST 4
div.row
  /// Looped from each
  div.span6
    ..More content
  div.span6
```

//EDIT Here is my solution, with mixin

```
mixin blogPost(post)
  div.span6
    ...code

div
  - for (var i = 0; i < postList.length; i++)
    div.row
      mixin blogPost(postList[i])
      - if (i + 1 < postList.length)
        mixin blogPost(postList[i + 1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ill post the solution here

```
mixin blogPost(post)
  div.span6
    ...code

div
  - for (var i = 0; i < postList.length; i++)
    div.row
      mixin blogPost(postList[i])
      - if (i + 1 < postList.length)
        mixin blogPost(postList[i + 1])
```